# Which speech recognition system to use?

Tags: android, ios, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech

I want to implement following idea. I need my user to open web page or mobile application and say something. The speech of user will be recorded end sent to a local server, and I want the server to process it and generate some voice output.

My questions are next:

1. Which Speech Recognition API to use? In my case audio file will be
   sent to server, and after that it will be processed.
2. I need to recognize names and last names. This is a potential problem, because I don't live in English-speaking country, and names and last names could be rather strange to English-speaker. I want to implement this by adding required names and last names to "dictionary" of speech-recognizing system, so I need one that can expand its dictionary.
3. I need a free decision.

So, which Speech Recognizing API should I use in implementation of my idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had success in the past using the [CMU Sphinx toolkit](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) for speech recognition. I had used a variation of it within in Android application. If I remember correctly it did allow the creation of a dictionary of specific words to look for so it may fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you have a look at the Speech API from Nuance. They have the best on the market and are available on any platform. We use them for our product LinguSocial, which offers near real-time voice call translation to mobiles & landlines and also machine translated video chats.